# Possible memory leak in JDBC bulkcopy

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, sql-server-2012, sqlbulkcopy

I am writing a Spring Boot 2 application and I am using SQL Bulk Copy functionality for inserting several records in a SQL Server 2012 database.
Every time I insert ~700 row i have a leak of 600 MB

I have tried Microsoft driver version 6.4.0.jre8 and 7.2.2.jre8 but anything changes.
I have tried changing the Hikari Connection Pool for the tomcat one but the result is the same.

For invoking the Microsoft API I am using a wrapper framework (https://github.com/bytefish/JSqlServerBulkInsert) but the code is clean:

```java
 public void saveAll(Connection connection, SQLServerBulkCopyOptions options, Stream<TEntity> entities) {
        // Create a new SQLServerBulkCopy Instance on the given Connection:
        try (SQLServerBulkCopy sqlServerBulkCopy = new SQLServerBulkCopy(connection)) {
             // Set the Options:
            sqlServerBulkCopy.setBulkCopyOptions(options);
            // The Destination Table to write to:
            sqlServerBulkCopy.setDestinationTableName(mapping.getTableDefinition().GetFullQualifiedTableName());
            // The SQL Records to insert:
            ISQLServerBulkRecord record = new SqlServerRecord<TEntity>(mapping.getColumns(), entities.iterator());
            // Finally start the Bulk Copy Process:
            sqlServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(record);
            // Handle Exceptions:
        } catch (SQLServerException e) {
            // Wrap it in a RunTimeException to provide a nice API:
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

When I use Eclipse memory Analyzer I have these results:

- With Hikari:

> "One instance of "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolEntry" loaded by
>   "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x81611758" occupies 640.619.616
>   (95,94 %) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of
>   "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "".
>
> Keywords com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolEntry java.lang.Object[]
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x81611758 "

- With Tomcat:

> "One instance of "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool" loaded
>   by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x81614fa0" occupies
>   640.805.840 (95,92 %) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "".
>
> Keywords java.lang.Object[] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @
>   0x81614fa0 org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool"

Comment: How do you know it's a leak and not memory not yet reclaimed by GC? Calling `close()` does not guarantee that all the data is immediately removed from memory.

Comment: I am forcing GC and the gap of 600 MB does not change. Also Eclipse Memory Analyzer detects it as possible leak

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the driver. I was using a list inside a method and expecting to be collected after the method scope. I assigned the reference to null (previous I cleared the collection) and the GC could collect it.